# days in rows and months in columns melt into time series R

Tags: r, date, matrix, time-series, melt

I have time series data in the following structure:

```
dat=data.frame("Year"=rep(2005,31),
               "Day"=seq(1:31),
               "JANUARY"=sample(seq(1:100),31,T),
               "FEBRUARY"=c(sample(seq(1:100),28),NA,NA,NA),
               "MARCH"=sample(seq(1:100),31),
               "APRIL"=c(sample(seq(1:100),30),NA),
               "MAY"=sample(seq(1:100),31),
               "JUNE"=c(sample(seq(1:100),30),NA),
               "JULY"=sample(seq(1:100),31),
               "AUGUST"=sample(seq(1:100),31),
               "SEPTEMBER"=c(sample(seq(1:100),30),NA),
               "OCTOBER"=sample(seq(1:100),31),
               "NOVEMBER"=c(sample(seq(1:100),30),NA),
               "DECEMBER"=sample(seq(1:100),31)
```

Closest I can think is to melt the data by day and year

```
melt(dat,id.vars=c("Day","Year"))
```

coercing to a date

```
dat$Date<-paste(dat$Day,dat$variable,dat$Year,sep="-")
dat$Date<-as.Date(dat$Date,"%d-%B-%Y")
dat<-dat[which(is.na(pm25$Date)!=T),]
```

Is there a more efficient and non-stupid way of doing any of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the Hadley approach using *gather* from tidyr, *mutate* from dplyr, *str_c* from stringr, and *as_date* from lubridate.  It makes things flow pretty smoothly.

```
library('dplyr')
library('tidyr')
library('stringr')
library('lubridate')

Dates <- dat %>% 
  gather(Month, Value, JANUARY:DECEMBER) %>% 
  mutate(Date_1 = str_c(Day, Month, Year, sep = "-"),
         Date_2 = as_date(Date_1, "%d-%B-%Y")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Date_2))
```